# How to plot satellite ground track on to a map projection in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to plot the ground-track of a satellite in a given orbit in mapview. I already have the data sets that contain the x, y, z position of the satellite as well as the longitude and latitude data. I only have a problem with plotting it.

Comment: please review my answer and let me know if you're missing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MKGeodesicPolyline for that. More info [here](http://nshipster.com/mkgeodesicpolyline/)

```
//Replace this with whatever you have for a source of locations
var satellitePathLocations = [
    CLLocation(latitude: -73.761105, longitude: 41.017791),
    CLLocation(latitude: -73.760701, longitude: 41.019348),
    CLLocation(latitude: -73.757201, longitude: 41.019267),
    CLLocation(latitude: -73.757482, longitude: 41.016375),
    CLLocation(latitude: -73.761105, longitude: 41.017791)
]


var coordinates = satellitePathLocations.map({(location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in return location.coordinate})

let polyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
mapView.add(polyline)

// On your MKMapView delegate

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKGeodesicPolyline {
        var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 2
        return polylineRenderer
    }

    return nil
}
```